# Can one show NP-completeness by showing a reduction to 3SAT?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, decision-problem

The standard technique to show NP-completeness of $L$ seems to be to show that $L$ is in NP, and then to show that some NP-complete language can be reduced to it. What if one tried to show it the other way, i.e., if L $\leq $ 3SAT?

Wouldn't that be one one step way of showing that the language $L$ is in NP-complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to your proof method. The empty language reduces to 3SAT, yet it isn't NP-hard.

If you reduce $L$ to 3SAT, then you can conclude that $L$ is in NP, that's it.

Comment: Since 3SAT can be reduced to the Halting problem, wouldn't the empty language too be reducible to it? And by extension be in NP-Hard.

Comment: The empty language reduces to any language except for the complete language.